# ISAPI Rewrite Syntax Help?

Tags: asp.net, isapi

I have the following

```
RewriteMap mapfile txt:D:\mysite\urls.txt
RewriteRule ^([^?/]+)\.htm  /vehicle.aspx?e=${mapfile:$1} [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm $1\.aspx
```

Now my problem is, I want to make the url's look like this for the /vehicles.aspx page (Which I am reading from a file)

```
/my-chevrolet-camaro.htm
```

Which is working fine - The problem I have now is if any of the REAL pages in the root are browsed to it throws a page not found??  For example

```
default.htm
```

Would throw a 404!!  What syntax do I need to say check the list and then just carry on as normal?

Answer (score 0):

Your last rule, i.e.,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm $1\.aspx
```

maps *.htm to *.aspx.

This would mean that default.htm would be rewritten to default.aspx. If you don't have a default.aspx, then a 404 would be thrown. Does that help?